# How to retrieve Javascript/HTML in CLR

Tags: javascript, .net, clr, webresource.axd

I know I can put HTML and JavaScript into a separate projects and then access the code by pulling it from the dll from the context of another project.

But, how do I go about accessing the code that was put in the dll?

The purpose of this is for distributing modules. I'm using MVC 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you added it to the project as an embedded resource.

You can write `typeof(MyType).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Folder.File.js")`

Comment: Yes I did. What is the value of (MyType), the type of the current project?

Comment: @Don: Any type in the desired assembly.